# Vector surface integral - pseudovector?

Tags: vectors, differential-forms, surface-integrals

I'm teaching myself differential forms in relation to vector calculus. I understand that for a vector field

$$\mathbf{v}\left(x,y,z\right)=f_{1}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_{x}+f_{2}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_{y}+f_{3}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_{z}$$there is a corresponding 1-form$$\omega_{1}=f_{1}\,dx+f_{2}\,dy+f_{3}\,dz$$and 2-form$$\omega_{2}=f_{1}\,dy\wedge dz+f_{2}\,dz\wedge dx+f_{3}dx\wedge dy.$$

My question was prompted by reading Frankel, *The Geometry of Physics*, where (p99) he gives the surface integral of a 2-form $\beta^{2}$,

[image]

and then goes on to say:

“Suppose that one insists on writing this in terms of the vector, or rather the pseudovector $\mathbf{B}$, associated to $\beta^{2}$.”

He seems to be saying that in the context of finding the surface integral of a 2-form, the corresponding vector is always a pseudovector.

Why is that? And, in general, does the 2-form $\omega_{2}$ always correspond to a pseudovector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a pseudovector is that it changes sign when you change the orientation of the ambient space. You start with the vector field  $\mathbf v$ and it corresponds — given the duality coming from the metric — to the $1$-form $\omega_1$. Where does $\omega_2$ come from? Well, $\omega_2 = \star\omega_1$, and the Hodge star operator changes sign here when you change the orientation on $\Bbb R^3$. Thus, the recipe for $\mathbf B$ depends on the orientation choice.

Comment: Sorry to labour this, but what if $\mathbf{v}\left(x,y,z\right)$ is an ordinary (ie non-pseudo) vector and I then associate it with the 2-form $\omega_{2}$? Does this association somehow change $\mathbf{v}$ to a pseudovector?

Comment: No, it does not. If, however, you start with a well-defined $2$-form $\omega$, independent of the orientation choice, then going backwards, you take the (pseudo)vector associated to $\star\omega$ and *this* depends on the orientation.